# Why is kdeplot scaled off the y-axis when including in Seaborn PairGrid?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I had to [follow the instructions posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862882/why-are-no-colors-shown-in-kde-subplots-in-seaborn-pairplot) to create a scatterplot matrix that uses multiple colors to distinguish among the treatments in my dataset ([this seems to still be on open issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1265)).

My problem is that some of my kde subplots are off the y-axis scale: [Leaf area index PairGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orhFl.jpg)

This doesn't seem to be nearly as severe of an issue using the "Iris" dataset, but I still see it happening in the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th subplots ([see the PairGrid in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862882/why-are-no-colors-shown-in-kde-subplots-in-seaborn-pairplot)).

How do I adjust the y-axis scale so that all of my kde data fit into the sublots?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

g =  sns.PairGrid(iris, hue='species', size=2)

def f(x, **kwargs):
    kwargs.pop("color")
    col = next(plt.gca()._get_lines.prop_cycler)['color']
    sns.kdeplot(x, color=col, **kwargs)

g.map_diag(f)
g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter)
g.add_legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The linked question does have a [mcve]. Why do you post a code which is not reproducible instead of using the available code?

Comment: I included a link to the screenshot from my output and thought it would be appropriate to show the code I used since the original code is posted on the other post that I referenced. I apologize for the apparent confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is now fixed in version 0.8.1 of seaborn.

You may simply use

```
g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue="species", palette="Set2", diag_kind="kde", size=2.5)
```

as stated in the documentation.

Also the workaround posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45865124/4124317) will work as expected in seaborn 0.8.1 and not have any yscaling issues.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I installed what I thought was the latest version of seaborn earlier today via conda install (v. 0.8). I just installed [from Github](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn) and now the colors are differentiated and the y-axis is scaled appropriately. However, I don't believe the y-scaling issue was addressed in that workaround as you mention. You can see that the kde curves are off the y-axis scale.. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: No it is not addressed in the workaround, but since it is fixed in the newest version, there should not be any need to do it anyways.